# Possibly broken WAN port: how to verify and how to work around?

Tags: router, lan, openwrt, wan, busybox

Is it possible to say for sure if the WAN port is dead?  The green LED blinking is inconsistent and happens while connection and some time after, for me it looks like working.

The context: when I connect ISP cable directly to laptop, it is working fine, but when I connect cable to router WAN port [it shows "Internet not connected"](https://cs5-2.4pda.to/19680337.jpg) in router dashboard, previously it worked fine.

The router is Phicomm K3C, you probably never heard about it, it has stock firmware which is a cutted fork of OpenWRT, I can connect to it through Telnet and it has stripped BusyBox utilities.

It is possible to check WAN in bash or some way else?

Also this device has unofficial OpenWRT firmware (it is not in the officially supported list) and this firmware is reported to be buggy. I can install it, will it help?

I found anecdotal evidences that OpenWRT allows re-assigning WAN to any LAN port.

Comment: When you connect your laptop directly to the WAN port on the Router it shows "_internet not connected_"? That would be as expected, surely - you should typically connect a modem / other network to the WAN port, not a computer.

Comment: There is a simple solution to test the WAN port - connect another router or PC (that has a DHCP server enabled and is optionally connected to internet) to the WAN port of the _Phicomm K3C_ (set its WAN mode to Dynamic IP) and check if gets a lease from DHCP. Connect another device to the LAN/WLAN of the K3C and check if internet works.

Comment: `When you connect your laptop directly to the WAN port on the Router it shows "internet not connected"?` no, I see *Internet not connected* in Web-GUI of my router, where it checks signal on WAN, corrected misleading wording. Added the screenshot

Comment: `There is a simple solution to test the WAN port - connect another router or PC to the WAN port and check if gets a lease from DHCP` thanks for suggestion, will try. Does Win10 has built-in DHCP server? I believe no, only client. Can [ICS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) be utilized for that?

Comment: Yes, ICS enables DHCP server in Windows (usually in the 192.168.137.x range). Or you can simply use another router with DHCP server enabled (i.e. LAN of DHCP-enabled router connected to WAN of _Phicomm K3C_)